# Having Issue on Loading <tr> text into Element of An Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know how I can store the text values of each row `<tr>` in an element of an array and adding space between `<td>`

some thing like

```
arr = ["Jill, Smith, 50","Eve, Jackson, 94", "John, Doe, 80",... ]
```

What is happening now is I am getting this in result!

```
["↵    Jill↵    Smith       ↵    50↵  ", "↵    Eve↵    Jackson      ↵    94↵  ", "↵    John↵    Doe     ↵    80↵  ", "↵    Mac↵    Raian        ↵    34↵  "]
```

Here is the code I have

```js
var arr = [];
$('#authors tr').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="authors" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mac</td>
    <td>Raian</td>  
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>  
    
</table>
```

Comment: `arr.push($('td',this).text());`

Comment: Thanks Pranav but how about adding space between the `<td>` ?

Comment: @Behseini you should clarify if you need the `tds` to be separated by a `', '` or a `' '` because your example has commas yet you ask for spaces.

Answer (score 4):

```
var arr = [];
$('#authors tr').each(function () {
  var tdval = '';  
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    tdval += $(this).text()+', ';
    })
    arr.push(tdval);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Use this code

Comment: I think the OP wants the text joined on `', '` and not `' '`

Comment: he want to add space, check this line "and adding space between "

Comment: yet he has commas in his example. I guess he should clarify.

Comment: that won't work because it will add commas to the last element as well, and that's not correct... That's why I mentioned this cause it's not a short fix :)

Comment: you are right but what if we remove last comma by regular expression or tdval.trim().trim(','); just guess

Comment: You can just use the fact that `each` passes an index as the first argument, and add commas unless that index is the **last** index (i.e. equal to the number of `tds`). **However**, I think @Behseini should clarify what exactly he needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96403/discussion-between-susain-and-nem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)** instead of **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**

1. Use **[`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)** to iterate generate text array
2. Retrieve the text array  using **[`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)**
3. Join array value using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
var arr = $('#authors tr').map(function() {
  return $('td', this).map(function() { // ietrate over td nside tr
      return $(this).text(); // return text content inside
    }).get().join() // get text array and join the array values with space          
}).get()

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="authors" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mac</td>
    <td>Raian</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `map` and `join()`.

```js
var arr = [];
$('#authors tr').each(function() {
  arr.push(
    $(this).find("td").map(function(i, o) {
      return $(o).text();
    }).get().join(",")
  )
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="authors" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mac</td>
    <td>Raian</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What's the point of adding the same code as [Pranav C Balan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33968557/3928341) 7 minutes later?

Comment: oops, just saw that !! I was bit late in typing that time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way but this will do the trick

```
var arr = [];
$('#authors tr').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).text().trim().replace(/(\n)/g, ','));
});
console.log(arr);
```

It basically removes the beginning and ending new lines and then does a replace of the other new lines with commas